# Iterator for resourcemanager.NewProjectsClient().ListProjects() doesn't work as expected in GCP

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, iterator

The `google.golang.org/api/iterator` for storage seems to work as expected — I'm able to loop over >6K bucket objects.  However, when using `google.golang.org/api/iterator` on projects, I only get 3 projects before `iterator.Done`.  I expect >10K.

I've read these for reference:
https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/reference/cloud.google.com/go/resourcemanager/latest/apiv3#cloud_google_com_go_resourcemanager_apiv3_ProjectsClient_ListProjects
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/wiki/Iterator-Guidelines
https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/iterator
https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/resourcemanager/apiv3
https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/resourcemanager/apiv3/resourcemanagerpb
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/main/resourcemanager/apiv3/projects_client_example_test.go

My questions:

- what am I doing wrong?
- should the iterator work the same as with the storage API? (I assume so)
- do I have to use a pager in combination with the iterator? (I tried this)
- do I have to make multiple calls to `ListProjects()`?  I see there is the `PageToken` field in the `ListProjectsRequest` type. (I tried this too)

Test code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    resourcemanager "cloud.google.com/go/resourcemanager/apiv3"
    resourcemanagerpb "cloud.google.com/go/resourcemanager/apiv3/resourcemanagerpb"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
)

func printFields(p *resourcemanagerpb.Project) {
    fmt.Printf("Name\t%s\n", p.Name)
    fmt.Printf("ProjectId\t%s\n", p.ProjectId)
    fmt.Printf("DisplayName\t%s\n\n", p.DisplayName)
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    c, err := resourcemanager.NewProjectsClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("NewProjectsClient() error: %v", err)
    }
    defer c.Close()
    req := &resourcemanagerpb.ListProjectsRequest{
        Parent: "organizations/12345678912", // CHANGE-ME
    }
    it := c.ListProjects(ctx, req)
    for {
        project, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Next() error: %v", err)
        }
        printFields(project)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `ListProjectsRequest`:

```
type ListProjectsRequest struct {
        // Required. The name of the parent resource whose projects are being listed.
        // Only children of this parent resource are listed; descendants are not
        // listed.
```

... thanks to Manjuram Perumalla for pointing this out.

So the iterator works as expected.  I had the wrong idea (that it would return all projects in an org).  The call to ListProjects() only lists projects for a given parent.  So, to get all projects in an org:

1. call ListProjects() with org as parent
2. get all folders in org

   a. recusively descend each folder calling ListProjects() with folder as parent

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).